# adding /using silverlight ddl in visual studio 2008

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to add silverlight3.0 ddl in visual studio 2008 but getting the following error any help.

**

> error in loading type from assembly.Could not load file or assembly
>   system.windows

**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repairing the Silverlight Tools installation?
And do you have Silverlight SDK installed?

The Silverlight SDK can be installed using the following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16011

The Silverlight Addon for VS 2008 SP1 can be found here which includes SDK and other components:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9394

You may also check the following:
http://hmcguirk.blogspot.com/2011/02/silverlight-could-not-load-file-or.html

Hope it helps!